# When does perturbative renormalization group (RG) fail?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory

In the typical perturbative RG scheme, one looks for fixed points by computing the beta function after truncating the interaction strength (say $\alpha$) to some desired order. In particular, we're taught that perturbative RG is really only valid in the vicinity of the fixed point, but people draw out the full RG flows regardless. Are there textbook cases where perturbative RG fails outside of its domain of validity, e.g. it misses an intermediate-coupling fixed point?

Comment: It sounds like you are mostly interested in high energy theory, but a couple of examples from stat phys: 1) many disordered materials have a disorder critical point at T=0, and there is a 'theorem' that shows that the properties of this critical point in $d$ dimensions are related to the properties of the zero-disorder $T \neq 0$ fixed point in $d-2$ dimensions, at all orders in perturbation theory. However, this "dimensional reduction" can be invalidated due to non-perturbative effects. e.g., in the random field Ising model (RFIM) it breaks down at $d \sim 5.1$.

Comment: A second set of examples involving an intermediate coupled fixed points in reaction-diffusion models are reviewed in this paper: arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0511456 . In particular, a) in a voter model there is a critical point that is not Gaussian in any dimension, and b) in a similar model that there is a transition to an absorbing state in $d>2$ dimensions that is missed by perturbation theory.